# How to get verbose log from react-scripts build script?

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

I upgraded to the `react-scripts` v5 and my build fails with an unuseful message:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '...' in '/project/src'
```

As you can see it only tells me that there was a problem in the `src` directory, which is literally the entire project.

How can I increase verbosity of this script?

Comment: 10 upvotes and no answer. This sucks :|

Comment: @dwjohnston I strongly recommend that you migrate to Vite. We did it, and we're extremely happy. It had its own costs, but we're very happy to abandon CRA.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the verbosity of error messages with react-scripts v5, modify your build script in the package.json file like this:

For Linux/Unix/macOS:

```
"build": "CI=false react-scripts build",
```

For Windows:

```
"build": "set CI=false&& react-scripts build",
```

This will provide more detailed error messages during the build process.

Answer (score -3):

Do you have the `index.js` file inside `project/src`? Does it have import from `...` (or `/project/index.js`)?

Comment: I do have `index.js` inside `src` directory. But it does not import `...` from anywhere. Also my code works just fine with `npm run start`. It only fails for `npm run build`.